# Jsonstring passed from ajax request converted to byte[] array on the server side

Tags: c#, json, arrays

I have a question. i know i can pass a jsonstring via ajax request to the server as string but can i convert the passed jsonstring to byte[] array on the server side? can you show me codes on how to do it? i tried this one.

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputstring);
```

Comment: what language is that on the server side? C# ? the json is just a string... you can do with it whatever you wish or whatever the language knows on the servers side

Comment: yes c#. but with the {} and '' will it still work? can you give me a sample code on how can i convert a json string to byte[] array?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample code that converts a JSON-string to a byte-array:

```
public static byte[] JsonStringToByteArray(string jsonString)
{
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(jsonString.Substring(1, jsonString.Length - 2));
}
```

Hope this helps!